# Remove App Pool All TimeSpan through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis

I am using IIS server, want to remove app pool all element of an array, How can I Do this with help of PowerShell command.

With below command I can get an array of app pool specific times array.
Can any one help me on finding command.

```
Get-WebConfiguration ` 
 /system.applicationHost/applicationPools/applicationPoolDefaults/recycling/periodicRestart/schedule/add | 
   select value
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the command which I was looking for

```
remove-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool -Name recycling.periodicrestart.schedule.collection
```